# Common process for creating social media content?

Tags: marketing, process

I've been tasked with defining a process to write and share content to social media. We are a small company and while we have people that create content, there will be nobody fully dedicated to it.

I've seen some content created by a previous employee and it's very bad, so I'm trying to figure out how to create a foolproof method so the content is at least readable.

How is this commonly done?

Comment: The first thing you can do is clear the jargon out of your vocabulary. *Task* is not a verb.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum - Unfortunately, it *is* a word. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no foolproof method, but here are some ideas.

First, go through the documentation with someone from different parts of the company and have them highlight when they find a line that they think is most important:

1. Can you form the comment in an interactive question?
2. Can you make the comment stand out in 70 characters or less followed by a clickable link?

Other tips:

Follow the rule of 3rds. If you company's focus is "Blah", only make 1 of 3 posts about "Blah". Two posts in between each "Blah" post should be interactive and customer focused. The other two posts could be success stories or giveaways or whatever.

Always have a second person review the posts before they go out.

Maybe have a check list like this:

Post is "correct"

1. Spell check.
2. Grammar check (unless intentional for space issues.)
3. Useless word check.
4. Check that no word and hashtag are the same.
5. Are correct people or hashtags tagged?

Content

1. Is it safe for work (SFW)
2. Is it accurate? Fact checked?
3. Can anything be offensive?
4. Can anything be misinterpreted as offensive?
5. Would any customer stop being a customer because you post this?

Post is engaging 1 2 3 4 5 (1 worst 5 best)

1. Is it a question? +1
2. Is it funny, awesome, nostalgic, exciting, or important? +1
3. Is it boring? -1
4. Is it selling something? -1
5. Is it giving something? +1 (you sell more giving than by selling)
6. *Safely controversial? +1
7. Was your last post about the same thing? -1

*Safely = Who is better Superman or Batman? Unsafe = political, religious, bigoted or otherwise negatively controversial - unless you are representing such group and trying to change the world for the better.

Comment: hi Rhyous I wanted to know, how are posts commonly reviewed? I'm thinking on simply creating a dummy account and let people post there. I'm not sure if it's such a great idea, but I cannot think of any other good way to do this

Comment: See edits in response. I gave you some other ideas in check list form. Hope that helps.